On cross-play Minecraft servers, what happens to parity issues?
On cross-play Minecraft servers, such as MysticMC, how do features that behave differently depending on Java vs. Bedrock behave?
Based on what I have experienced, it seems like GUI, bridging, and sunsets behave like Bedrock, whereas everything else behaves like Java!
I really want to know this, as I just got messed up by a parity issue (cats run from crouching players on Java)!

Does this answer your question?

Current Limitations
With Geyser being a protocol translator between two different games
with two different codebases, there are a handful of limitations that
Geyser is unfortunately unable to handle.  Despite Minecraft Bedrock
and Java being quite close in comparison, there are some vast
differences in many areas.
Unfixable
The following things cannot be fixed without changes to Bedrock or the
Java protocol in general. As of now, they are not fixable in Geyser.

Custom heads in inventories
Clickable links in chat
Glowing effect
Crafting in the 2x2 menu while in creative mode - with the GeyserOptionalPack, this grid is hidden as it does not exist on Java.
Distinguishing between left and right clicks in inventories
Redstone dot blockstates
"Can be placed on/destroyed" tag for some blocks - for example, different slab variants that aren't yet split up into separate blocks.
Potion colors implemented using NBT
Various command arguments for any command that doesn't use the Minecraft Brigadier library
Anything that relies on tab complete or typing in the chat UI (related to the above) - Bedrock sends no packet that indicates they
are in this menu
Unable to see banner layers past 6
Movement issues around bamboo due to offset differences between Java and Bedrock: Hurricane can work around it.
Custom anvil recipes or custom smithing table ingredients/patterns (GeyserMC/Geyser#4706)
Heights lower than -64 or higher than 320 in the overworld with extended height enabled, and heights lower than 0 or higher than 256
in other dimensions
(GeyserMC/Geyser#3804)
Dolphin's Grace potion effect visuals (effects should still work correctly)
Invisible item frames
Blocks (excluding jack-o-lantern) on entity heads (E.G. armor stands, players)
Some block state changes are controlled client side, and are not influenced by the debug stick - fences for example.
(GeyserMC/Geyser#3125)
Custom beacon base blocks (GeyserMC/Geyser#2301)
these are hardcoded on Bedrock edition.
Climbable blocks changed by datapacks (GeyserMC/Geyser#4051)
Custom enchantments/sweeping edge (GeyserMC/Geyser#3121)
"Bordure Indented" pattern shape not appearing on the Bedrock side in the loom
(GeyserMC/Geyser#3183)
Gliding without elytras/custom elytras (GeyserMC/Geyser#3255, GeyserMC/Geyser#3299)
Custom furnace cook times (GeyserMC/Geyser#4104)
Maximum sign length different on Java/Bedrock edition (GeyserMC/Geyser#4130)

Fixable With GeyserOptionalPack
The following changes are supported with the
GeyserOptionalPack, which is a
Bedrock resource pack you can install for additional functionality for
features Bedrock does not natively support:

Custom armor stand poses
Illusioners
Hit particles and other miscellaneous particles not natively in Bedrock
Offhand animations
Shulker invisibility
Spectral arrow texture
Scoreboard width that matches Java
Inventory UI changes to match Java


Source

No it does not, I want a list of the parity differences with which one occurs on cross play servers

Try googling ;)

tried that didn’t work

Harrychink, click on the link aytimothy embedded in the words “Try googling”. It brings you to a webpage that explains exactly what you’re asking about, and is part of what they used to write their answer for you. Also, the other links throughout the answer. It seems like it answers your question pretty well, so what’s not up to standard?

@daemons it show’s pairity issues but not which one applies to crossplay

@Harrychink ALL of them do. Like not being able to click on links... Or bedrock players have longer reach (also why Hypixel support is impossible)... or swamp huts not having potions (because of Java generation)

Ok so on crossplay servers bedrock players have longer reach but don’t get potions from swamp huts… what about the other parity issues

@Harrychink The wiki page has it all (that is known). You're asking for more, yet when shown there are more than the little peephole that you're looking through, you reject the possibility of it altogether. (also a quote from a certain movie)

@aytimothy during crossplay, with pocket edition controls, when does it act like Java, and when does it act like bedrock

From your perspective: always like Bedrock; your control scheme makes no difference regardless but the server sees it Java, which is why some servers sees reach as a reach hack (even though it's expected/normal for Bedrock)

@aytimothy then why did cats run away from me when I was sneaking like they would in java
